# Live USB Boot error

Tags: live-usb

I have a system without a hard drive.
I've used the start-up disk creator to copy the 13.04 .iso to the usb.
I've used the same USB on multiple systems to install to a second USB stick.
On this system, it starts at the typical install screen

```
GNU GRUB version 2.00-19ubuntu2
```

I click on `Try Ubuntu without installing` and I get this

```
error: invalid cluster 149xxxxxx
```

and then I get a giant screen  of text that looks like

```
[    30.xxxxxxxx] perf samples too long {350648 > 200000}, lowering kernel.perf event_max sample rate
```

When I Click "`Install`" at the Gnu Grub screen, I get the Ubuntu logo with the 5 dots below it and it stalls.

please help

Comment: Is there anything I can add to this question to get some more feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the clue is "**error: invalid cluster 149xxxxxx**". I had something similar with the corrupted geometry of an SD card recently.

I used testdisk (TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013) written by

Christophe GRENIER 
http://www.cgsecurity.org

It found and fixed the invalid clusters. But take care that you are talking to the correct device, or you will be very sorry!